# Install composer (Permission denied) Symfony

Tags: linux, permissions, composer-php

For one reason or another, I can't install composer on my system
I am with CENTOS operating system and the html folder has 755 permissions

> [ErrorException] file_put_contents (/var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/composer/installed.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Do you have some suggestions to fix my problem?

Comment: Please, tell us how you installed composer and the command you are running to install the dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

How are you trying to install composer? You must just be logged in and run these commands:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Just like written inside https://getcomposer.org/download/
After you'll be done, run this command:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

That's enough, you can use composer like these:

```
composer require ...
```

Comment: Warning: copy(composer-setup.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1

On first line.. with this php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

Comment: with composer require... [ErrorException]                                                              
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: You don't have permissions to create files in your directory, but if my answer not useful for you, I can't help